# Split List into Sublist using Linq based on content of list

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

This is similar, but not quite what is being asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

I have a list that I want to break into sublists, but the break occurs based on the content of an entry and not a fixed size.

Original List = `[ split,1,split,2,2,split,3,3,3 ]`

becomes `[split,1]`, `[split,2,2]`, `[split,3,3,3]` or `[1]`, `[2,2]`, `[3,3,3]`

Comment: What do you want it to break on?

Comment: What's the type of your list? `object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe?

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6 };
var subLists = list.Split(0).ToList();
```

---

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, T divider)
{
    var temp = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (!item.Equals(divider))
        {
            temp.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return temp;
            temp = new List<T>();
        }
    }

    if (temp.Count > 0) yield return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `foreach` is more appropriate and readable than a linq approach:

```
var originalList = new List<string>(){"split","1","split","2","2","split","3","3","3"};
var result = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> subList = new List<string>();
foreach(string str in originalList)
{
    if(str=="split")
    {
        subList = new List<string>();
        result.Add(subList);
    }
    subList.Add(str);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/UmCtB6)